# How to merge nested tuples

Tags: python, merge, tree

I have a set of nested tuples:

```
('id', ('name', ('name_float_fml',)), ('user', ('email',)), ('user', ('last_login',)))
```

I would like to combine lists with similar prefixes, resulting in:

```
('id', ('name', ('name_float_fml',)), ('user', ('email','last_login')))
```

Here is another example:

```
(('baz', ('bing', ('fizz', 'frozz', ('frazz', ('fry', 'bleep', 'blop'))))), ('baz', ('zap', ('zang',))), 'foo', 'bar')
```

would be merged to:

```
(('baz', (('bing', ('fizz', 'frozz', ('frazz', ('fry', 'bleep', 'blop')))), ('zap', ('zang')))), 'foo', 'bar')
```

These are intended to store paths from the root to the tree leaves:

- 'baz' -> 'bing' -> 'fizz', aka. `('baz' ('bing' ('fizz,)))`
- 'baz' -> 'zap' -> 'zang', aka `('baz' ('zap', ('zang',)))`
- 'baz' -> 'bing' -> 'frazz' -> 'blop', aka `('baz', ('bing', ('frazz', ('blop,))))`

I want to merge the elements where the leaves are reached by the same path. I hope this provides some amount of clarification.

I've written some code to do this, but it is ugly, verbose, and probably fragile. Is there some generic, concise, and/or efficient way of doing this? I imagine there may be some sort of `itertools` magic that I don't know about which would provide some elegant solution.

**Note:** I'm using python 2.4

Comment: those are tuples not lists. Also, if you only have 1 and 2-tuples, you should turn them into dicts

Comment: Sounds like a job for `reduce`!

Comment: Agreed, as presented, these are not lists, but they could well be. I've changed the terminology to match my example. Dicts are not an option, as in my use case, lists or tuples are required. These lists could be nested to arbitrary depth.

Comment: Your first tuple has one string(id) and three another tuples. How should it be handled? And could there be more tuple layers inside that, or just two?

Comment: I would be interested in seeing another example input and output set.

Comment: @vezult - I think my edit might match what you're looking for, if not, I agree with @Brent - please clarify further. @utdemir - he said the "lists could be nested to arbitrary depth" so recursion seems necessary. `This is so I can use multiple @s (you're all in the comment thread anyway so they don't do anything special)`

Comment: @utdemir: 'id' and 'name' are not siblings. 'id' and the tuple that contains 'name' are siblings. The root list exists by itself and has nothing to merge with. Only sibling items can be merged. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version that works for the examples you posted:

```
a = ('id', ('name', ('name_float_fml',)), ('user', ('email',)), ('user', ('last_login',)))
b = (('baz', ('bing', ('fizz', 'frozz',('frazz', ('fry', 'bleep', 'blop'))))), ('baz', ('zap', ('zang',))), 'foo', 'bar')

def preserve_path(value):
    if len(value) == 2 and isinstance(value[1], (list, tuple)):
        return [value]
    else:
        return value

def flatten_group(my_list):
    d = {}
    for item in my_list:
        # Only items with one string, followed by one tuple represent a path
        # segment. In all other situations, strings are leaves.
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)) and len(item) == 2:
            key, value = item
            if key in d:
                d[key].extend(flatten_group(preserve_path(value)))
            else:
                d[key] = preserve_path(list(flatten_group(value)))
        else:
            yield item

    for item in d.iteritems():
        yield item

print list(flatten_group(a))
# ['id', ('name', ['name_float_fml']), ('user', ['email', 'last_login'])]
print list(flatten_group(b))
# ['foo', 'bar', ('baz', [['bing', ('fizz', 'frozz', ('frazz', ('fry', 'bleep', 'blop')))], ('zap', ['zang'])])]
```

**Edit 3:** Updated with the coauthored version that works for both examples, and incorporates your restriction that it only has to consider merging items that are tuples/lists and contain two items. This also prevents additional flattening of merged items.

Comment: +1, This seems pretty good. I still think there's a `groupby` solution but am not able to work out the recursion for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using python 2.4, in which `collections.defaultdict` does not yet exist.

Comment: Updated to check for the key and act appropriately instead of using a `defaultdict`. Also removed an unnecessary `list` call.

Comment: This looks like it might do the trick, though I had to define `d` for you ;o)

Comment: My 2nd example probably didn't provide enough info. Your code chokes on that one because it assumes that there are only ever two elements in each tuple, which isn't guaranteed. For instance 'zang' is the only member of its tuple in example #2. I'll update my example for clarity.

Comment: You're still not well defined. How you define grouping by prefix if you can have more than one string before a tuple, or items of length above 2? For example, what if another item started `'fizz', 'frozz'`? If the rule is "merge the 2nd items of two-item lists with the same first item" it can be done, but as stated it doesn't have a well-defined solution.

Comment: @agf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2632/discussion-between-vezult-and-agf)

Comment: I've edited the version with your 2-tuple restriction into my post. I actually had a version that did that yesterday (it was identical) but it doesn't actually match your example -- notice `zang` is 5 lists in instead of 4 -- the `zap, (zang,)` list has become a child of `bing` as well as `baz`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the moving target. the 2nd example was contrived, and I messed it up a couple times. Anyway, I'm satisfied with your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function for doing this:

```
def merge(x, bases = (tuple, list)):
    for e in x:
        if type(e) in bases:
            for e in merge(e, bases):
                yield e
        else:
            yield e

tup = (0, (1, 3, 2), [5, (7, 2)])

print list(merge(tup))
# [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 2]
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I am looking for. I don't want to merely flatten the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
def combine(tuples):
    rlist = [tuples[0]]
    for k, g in groupby(tuples[1:], key=lambda t: t[0]):
        rlist.append(tuple((k, tuple(gg[1:][0][0] for gg in g))))
    return tuple(rlist)

sample = ('id', ('name', ('name_float_fml',)), ('user', ('email',)), ('user', ('last_login',)))
print combine(sample)
# ('id', ('name', ('name_float_fml',)), ('user', ('email', 'last_login')))
```

A recursive application of this process may be possible, for samples more complex than the one given in your question.